# How can I convert binary text to ASCII on terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, binary, ascii

I'm given a binary text file like 01101011011011110110010101101011011010100011001101110011
And I've to convert it to it's corresponding ASCII file.
How Should I proceed?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98948/ascii-to-binary-and-binary-to-ascii-conversion-tools

Comment: A file of 0 and 1 characters, or actual binary data where every 8 bits represents a character (In which case... what conversion?)?

Answer (score 3):

Would you try the following:

```
fold -w 8 inputfile | while read -r line; do
    hex=$(printf "%x" $(( 2#$line )))
    echo -ne "\x${hex}"
done
```

Result:

```
koekj3s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you have Python 3 :

```
$ MY_BINARY_STRING='01101011011011110110010101101011011010100011001101110011'
$ python3 -c "import binascii
print(str(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % int('0b'+'$MY_BINARY_STRING', 2)),'utf-8'))"
```

Outputs :

```
koekj3s
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution use `sed` and `bc`

```
echo "01101011011011110110010101101011011010100011001101110011" 
        | sed -r 's/(.{8})/\1;/g' 
        | sed 's/^/obase=16;ibase=2;/g' 
        | bc | sed 's/^/\\\\x/g' 
        | xargs echo -e | sed 's/ //g'
```